# Ping spikes and packet loss/connection drops to router

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, packet-loss

So I'm getting large ping spikes between my computer and router. I have ruled out the possibility of a faulty router as other devices on the network do not appear to get any service interruptions. I also recently moved my setup from one room to another (at least 20m away) so I don't think it is signal interference either.

I am using Windows 7 and the wireless card is some TP-Link model (Atheros AR922X according to device manager - I can't find the box of the card).

Here is what it looks like when pinging the router during a spike: [Imgur.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gvA9.png) There were also some "General failure" errors but I forgot to take a screenshot of them.

And a tracert: [Imgur.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiJhk.png)

Occasionally the wifi icon on the taskbar will have that yellow warning sign on it, or the connection will just drop entirely and give me unable to connect messages.

EDIT: When the connection drops entirely all but my home wifi network show under the list of networks. Other devices can still connect to the network fine. When I try to "troubleshoot" the problem windows tells me this: i.imgur.com/0igYuh5.png (Can't post more than 2 links because I'm new, pretty silly.)

Software issue? Faulty wireless card? How can I go about debugging this problem further? Thanks!

Comment: What wireless channel are you on? Are there any nearby wireless systems that you partially overlap?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's running on 2.4GHz (doesn't offer 5GHz) on channel 11. I live in a suburban area so there's a couple other networks that I have a weak connection to.

Comment: At least on channel 11, you can't partially overlap anyone else unless they're operating illegally. I assume you are configured for 20MHz channel width.

Comment: Correct, 20MHz. I have a hunch it's the wireless card I'm using.